# Changes in Database not reflected in JPA Entity

Tags: jpa, caching

I have a configuration table that I load at the beginning of the application. If I change any value on the database table, it is not reflected on the app and it is doing the query again.

```
    @Stateless()
@LocalBean()
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class DatosConfiguracionDAO {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DatosConfiguracionDAO.class);
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = Constantes.Conexiones.UNIT_PLACSP)
    private EntityManager em;
    
    
    public List<ConfiguracionEntity> findAllConfiguracion() throws GeacoPlacspException {
        try {
            
            TypedQuery<ConfiguracionEntity> query = em.createNamedQuery("ConfiguracionEntity.findAll",
                    ConfiguracionEntity.class);
            return query.getResultList();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("findAllConfiguracion" + e);
            throw new GeacoPlacspException(ErrorType.ERROR104,e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Entity

```
   @Entity
        @Table(name=NOMBRE_TABLA_CONFIGURACION)
        @NamedQuery(name="ConfiguracionEntity.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM ConfiguracionEntity c")
        public class ConfiguracionEntity extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
}
```

I'm using weblogic 12, and restart the weblogic is the only way to update the values in the app

Comment: Do you mean you change the database manually and want JPA to see the changed results?

Comment: Yes, exactly that

Comment: There is a @Cacheable-Annotation for Entities. Have a look at https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Cacheable.html

Comment: is this cache enabled by default? I dont have any enabled..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One an entity is in PersistanceContext it does not continually checks for entity's state in database (caching). In other words, it cannot see the changes made out side the PersistanceContext.
So, you need to refresh your entityManger by `em.refresh()` to reload the entity's latest state from database.

Also, keep in mind that using this method for entities that are not persisted yet, removed or detached, `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

An alternative solution is to simply clear your cache before fetching the entity's latest status by :

`em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll()`

P.S:
I do not know why you exactly need to change the entity's state outside the PersistanceContext and see the result in the context, but it seems like code smell.

Comment: Hi, the idea is a contiguration table in database. Therefore, I can change some configurations easily without re-deploy application, or change anything in the application, but with the problem I had, the configuration is not refreshed. I'll try your solution. I found one that is using : 
   query.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");
But I'm not sure what is doing...

Comment: about refresh query hint, take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjj.html